# how can i write this query entity framework

Tags: c#, sql, entity-framework

[image]

how can write this in CS what is should replace **** with ??

MSSQL Query:

```
SELECT        *FROM            Advertisement INNER JOIN
                     SubCategory ON Advertisement.SubCategoryID = SubCategory.SubCategoryID INNER JOIN
                     CategoryHaveSubCategory ON SubCategory.SubCategoryID = CategoryHaveSubCategory.SubCategoryID INNER JOIN
                     Category ON CategoryHaveSubCategory.CategoryID = Category.CategoryID WHERE        (CategoryHaveSubCategory.CategoryID = 1)
```

C# Query:

```
query = (from a in db.Advertisements
                 orderby a.Date descending
                 where **** && a.Deleted == false
                 select a).Skip(skip).Take(PAGE_SIZE);
```

Comment: please, provide the class structure

Comment: Please apply proper formatting. Your SQL code is virtually illegible. And as Fabio said, you really have to show the class model.

Comment: @GertArnold that is proper SQL, perhaps not the way most people are used to viewing it.  It looks like it was copied from a sql view as this is how sql formats views.

Comment: @JamesWilson I was aiming at the layout. I never understand why people don't do anything about this horizontal scrolling. It always drops my inclination to answer a few points.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You didn't include an important part of your `Advertisement` entity - the navigation properties. From the relation shown I assume you have something like this

```
class Advertisement
{
    // ...
    public SubCategory SubCategory { get; set; }
}
```

Then the condition you are asking for should be something like this

```
where a.SubCategory.Categories.Any(c => c.CategoryID == 1) && a.Deleted == false
```

Answer (score 0):

```
   query = (from a in db.Advertisements
                 orderby a.Date descending
                 where a.SubCategory.Categories.Any(c => c.CategoryID == 1) 
                 && a.Deleted == false
                 select a).Skip(skip).Take(PAGE_SIZE);
```